# In Haskell, is the map function a functor?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

The type of map  is: (a->b) -> [a] -> [b]

while the type of the functor fmap is:

Functor f => (a+b) -> f a -> f b
I read on wikipedia that map was a polymorphic morphism while fmap was a polytypic morphism but that doesn't really clear up things for me.

So my question is: is the map function a functor?

Comment: If you enable the `TypeApplications` extension, you can also see more clearly that `fmap` is actually a function that returns a type-specific implementation: `fmap @[] :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, `fmap @Maybe :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b`, etc. Without the extension, you can only let the type argument be applied implicitly, after the compiler has used type inference to determine which argument that should be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Haskell terms, `fmap` is a method in the typeclass `Functor`, not the functor itself. `[]`, `Maybe`, ... are type constructors which instantiates the class `Functor` and, abusing the language, you can say that "Maybe is a functor".

In mathematical terms, a functor (or more specifically in this case, an endofunctor in the category Hask, the category of Haskell types) is composed of two mappings: the first one from a type to another and the second from an arrow (`a -> b`) to another (`f a -> f b`) which preserves the structure. In that sense, `Maybe` is the first arrow which maps a type to another, say `Int` to `Maybe Int` and the `fmap` for `Maybe` is the second arrow.

Answer (score 4):

No, but any container that implements fmap is a functor. Lists implement fmap as well (give it a try!), so lists are functors. Map is just the implementation of fmap for lists.

Comment: A more correct answer would be "any _type_ that implements fmap _lawfully_ is a functor". Since `Functor` is not always container-like (for example `Cont r`), and not every implementation of `fmap` is a valid `Functor`.

Comment: In addition to what @cdk said, the "No" at the start of this answer, I'd say, is a bit misleading because all function types are functors and `map` is a function (so `map` has essentially the same relationship to `Functor` that the list `['a','b','c']` has).

Answer (score 3):

Like all `(->) r` types `map` is also a functor.

`(->) r` is actually just a simple function type like `r -> a` and all functions are functors. Like other functors you may think a function like  a container but you get the contained value when you apply a value. However as for a Functor instance we can not have a type with two type variables. That's why we partially apply it. Just like `Either a b` is done like [`instance Functor (Either a)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.Either.html#line-130). Since we are interested in the return value of a function the Functor instance of a function type is a partially applied `r -> a` which is `(->) r`.

So lets see a functions Functor instance.

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where  
  fmap f g = (\x -> f (g x))
```

So coming back to the question, `map` is a function with type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` and we can rewrite this  like `(a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])` so here `r` variable in the Functor instance stands for `a -> b` and `a` variable in the Functor instance stands for `[a] -> [b]`. So lets apply `fmap` on `map` like `fmap ($) map`. Which essentially means it will return us a function like `\x -> ($) map x`. Where `x` has to be a `(a -> b)` type function. So lets use `<$>`; the infix representation of `fmap` in the below example ;

```
Prelude> (($) <$> map) (+2) [1,2,3]
[3,4,5]
```

So.. yes `map` is a functor.

Comment: That's misleading at best; in fact I'd say it's _wrong_. What's a functor here is _the `(->) (a->b)` type constructor_; `map` happens to have a type of that form, but that doesn't make it a functor any more than `[1,2,3]` is a cons operator. That's just _a list_. Which, incidentally, isn't a functor either; the _list functor_ is the type-level entity `[] :: * -> *`, not any concrete value-level list.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I have just applied a function (`$`) over `map` by `fmap`. How is not `map` a functor if this is possible..? BTW what is a cons cell.?

Comment: If `map` were a functor, then fmapping anything over it would give you back some kind of “other flavour of `map`”. But it doesn't, it just gives you back _another function_. — — [Cons cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons_cell) —

Comment: Then instead of `($)`, for instance one could simply do `(.) <$> map` and can get a fancy function back. All functions are functors. You just apply their return value to the provided mapping function to obtain a new functionality. There might be simpler ways of doing this but this doesn't change the fact that `map`  is a functor.

Comment: The whole point of category theory is that it makes your constructions _as general as possible_. A functor that's only a functor if you fmap some vaguely specified particular sort of function wouldn't be worth its salt.

Comment: Anyway that's besides the point; “all functions are functors” is still wrong. “All types _T_ generate a functor whose objects are the types of function off _T_” would be the correct statement; that doesn't even say anything about _individual functions_, which are merely the members of said function-types. But category-theory wise, this kind of “membership of object” is a much more specific concept (it requires a [well-pointed category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-pointed_category)) than functors, which you can have between any categories.